# Haskell's reducing rule used in "distinct" function

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell by fp-course.  https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/5e0848b4eacb3ddff65553ab5beb6447b73f61b3/src/Course/State.hs#L182

I can implement `distinct` by feeling, but don't know exactly how `distinct` reduced by Haskell. So, I am not sure when `State` passes each `set` to `foldRight`.

All functions used by `distinct` as follow. I added `trace` to trace each expansion

```hs
distinct ::
  Ord a =>
  List a
  -> List a
distinct as = trace "distinct" $ eval (filtering filterFunc as) S.empty
                where filterFunc a = trace "filterFunc" (State $ \set -> trace "state" (if S.member a set
                                                                                         then (False, set)
                                                                                         else (True, S.insert a set)))

eval ::
  State s a
  -> s
  -> a
eval st s = trace "eval" (fst' $ runState st s)

fst' = trace "fst" fst

doFunc f s = trace "doFunc" (f s)

runState ::
  State s a
  -> s
  -> (a, s)
runState (State f) s = trace "runState" (doFunc f s)

filtering ::
  Applicative k =>
  (a -> k Bool)
  -> List a
  -> k (List a)
filtering p = trace "filtering" (foldRight f (pure Nil))
                where f a = trace "filtering where" (lift2 (\b as -> bool as (a :. as) b) (p a))

foldRight :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
foldRight _ b Nil      = b
foldRight f b (h :. t) = trace "foldRight" (f h (foldRight f b t))
```

`a = distinct (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. 3 :. 1 :. Nil :: List Int)` turns out `1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil` by following steps

```
>> a
distinct
eval
fst
runState
doFunc
filtering
foldRight
filtering where
runState
doFunc
runState
doFunc
filterFunc
state
foldRight
[1runState
doFunc
foldRight
filtering where
runState
doFunc
runState
doFunc
filterFunc
state
foldRight
,2runState
doFunc
foldRight
filtering where
runState
doFunc
runState
doFunc
filterFunc
state
foldRight
,3runState
doFunc
foldRight
filtering where
runState
doFunc
runState
doFunc
filterFunc
state
runState
doFunc
foldRight
filtering where
runState
doFunc
runState
doFunc
filterFunc
state
runState
doFunc
]
```

According to above ghc's expansion steps, `state`'s expansion place is strange. So I want to expaned manually step by step as follow.
But it is too difficult to manually expand as ghc does. Do you have some tool to automatically do this?

```hs
distinct (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. 3 :. 1 :. Nil :: List Int)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 1: Expand distinct
| distinct as = trace "distinct" eval (filtering filterFunc as) S.empty
|  where filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
|                                       then (False, set)
|                                       else (True, S.insert a set)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
eval (filtering filterFunc (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty
  where filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)
                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 2: Expand eval
| eval st s = trace "eval" fst' $ runState st s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fst' (runState (filtering filterFunc (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty)
  where filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 3: Expend fst
| (a, b) -> trace "fst" a
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = (runState (filtering filterFunc (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty)
        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 4: Expand runState
| runState (State f) s = trace "runState" (doFunc f s)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = doFunc f s
        doFunc f s = (runState (filtering filterFunc (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty)
        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 5: Expand doFunc
| doFunc ff ss = trace "doFunc" (ff ss)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = doFunc ff ss
        doFunc ff ss = ff ss
        ff ss = (runState (filtering filterFunc (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty)
        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 6: Expand filtering
| 
|  filtering p = trace "filtering" (foldRight f (pure Nil))
|                  where f a = trace "filtering where" (lift2 (\b as -> bool as (a :. as) b) (p a))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = doFunc ff ss
        doFunc ff ss = ff ss

        ff ss = (runState (foldRight f (pure Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil)) S.empty)
          where f a = lift2 (\b as -> bool as (a :. as) b) (p a)
        p = filterFunc

        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 7: Expand foldRight
| 
| foldRight :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
| foldRight _ b Nil      = b
| foldRight f b (h :. t) = trace "foldRight" (f h (foldRight f b t))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = doFunc ff ss
        doFunc ff ss = ff ss

        ff ss = (runState (f 1 (foldRight f (pure Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil))) S.empty)
          where f a = lift2 (\b as -> bool as (a :. as) b) (p a)
        p = filterFunc

        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| step 8: Expand filtering where
| 
| 
| ff ss = (runState (f 1 (foldRight f (pure Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil))) S.empty)
|   where f a acc = trace "filtering where" lift2 (\b as -> bool as (a :. as) b) (p a) acc
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
key
  where (key, value) = doFunc ff ss
        doFunc ff ss = ff ss

        ff ss = (runState expandFiltering S.empty)
          where expandFiltering = lift2 (\b as -> bool as (1 :. as) b) (filterFunc 1) (foldRight f (pure Nil) (1 :. 2 :. 1 :. Nil))

        filterFunc a = State $ \set -> if S.member a set
                                       then (False, set)
                                       else (True, S.insert a set)
```

Comment: `runState` doesn't expand next; `f` expands next.

Comment: `f` expand next. I added `trace "doFunc"` to trace `f`'s execution. In `step 5`, How does `f` executed in `step 5`? `step 4`'s expansion is strange also. Can I manually expend step by step?